# PHP - curl_multi_exec never completes

Tags: php, curl

I have tried many online examples of using [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). Unfortunately none of them "work" for me, as in they block forever and I never get a response.

- Example 1: http://syframework.alwaysdata.net/curl-multi-exec
- Example 2: http://www.somacon.com/p537.php

I tried modifying the some of the examples so that they will sleep if I get a -1 response which has no effect (other than stopping my CPU going to 100%). I tried both in the CLI and running as a webserver with the same result.

**Question:** Do these scripts work for other people or do they need modifying/updating for PHP 7.0? Perhaps there is a package other than php7.0-curl that I need to install?

#### Environment

I am runing PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment says at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php#115055, there's a problem on the official document. So the class of example 2 should look something like this. Changed the first while loop

```
class ParallelGet
{
  function __construct($urls)
  {
    // Create get requests for each URL
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {
      $ch[$i] = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
    }

    // Start performing the request
    do {
        $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
    } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    // Loop and continue processing the request
    while ($runningHandles && $execReturnValue == CURLM_OK) {

      // !!!!! changed this if and the next do-while !!!!!

      if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        usleep(100);
      }

      do {
        $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
      } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    }

    // Check for any errors
    if ($execReturnValue != CURLM_OK) {
      trigger_error("Curl multi read error $execReturnValue\n", E_USER_WARNING);
    }

    // Extract the content
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {
      // Check for errors
      $curlError = curl_error($ch[$i]);
      if($curlError == "") {
        $res[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]);
      } else {
        print "Curl error on handle $i: $curlError\n";
      }
      // Remove and close the handle
      curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
      curl_close($ch[$i]);
    }
    // Clean up the curl_multi handle
    curl_multi_close($mh);

    // Print the response data
    print_r($res);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have answered my question as I posted it so I am marking this as the complete answer. I think my next question belongs in a separate question, but do you happen to know why they aren't getting sent asynchronously but will process in a queue. E.g. try running the following code https://pastebin.com/ngu8L3kk after running a localhost webserver with a sleep(10), you will see that you don't get google or yahoo results, until the 10 seconds have past for the first request. Also, if you were to just use multiple localhost requests, it would take as long as the number of requests x 10 seconds.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what's going wrong I'd suggest to ask a new question, I'll find it.

Comment: thanks, will do after a little bit more investigation.

Comment: I found that I was doing something wrong with testing. All sorted :)